# How to dismiss an iPad Popover with Storyboard on iOS6?

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios6, uipopovercontroller

I have implemented a popover launched from a button. The popover displays. I've implemented a button, which when pressed should dismiss the popover. However, it doesn't and I have no idea why.

The .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ComposeViewController : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *popover;

- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

The .m file:

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {

NSLog(@"Save Button");


    [_popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
@end
```

If anyone has any ideas why, I'd be most grateful. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `[self dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

Popovers should be dismissed by the presenting controller. But, if your popover is setup as a modal view in storyboard you can use the following within the IBAction which would be in your "popover" controller:
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

And, I did notice something in your code: you are using "UIPopoverControllerDelegate"... is this in your popover? It should be in your presenting ViewController. As well... the IBAction should be in your popover controller.